# Do-for loop like do-while

Tags: c++

Is there a way to not evaluate the stopping condition before entering the for-loop? A sort of `do-for` loop?

```
for(int i = 0;
    f(i); // This check is guaranteed to pass when i is 0, 
          // and the check is expensive
    ++i) 
{
  // body
}
```

Is the only option to convert it to a `do-while` loop?

Comment: how about `i == 0 || expensive_check()`? `||` short-circuits and doesn't evaluate the second if the first is true

Comment: you can do the first operation outside the `for`. so `i` could start from 1 or be less than 9

Comment: @RisingSun That results in redundant code

Comment: I don't actually believe you. Can you show some benachmarks where the initial check matters?

Comment: @cigien The initial check is not like in the question. I call an API to decide if I should continue or not and that call is extremely expensive (about .5-1 seconds).

Comment: But is that call guaranteed to pass the first check? If it is, then you should just take the first iteration out of the loop.

Comment: @cigien It is. I suppose I can just leave the for-loop to be `true` and do a `break` check at the end.

Comment: Isn't that a do-while loop?

Comment: I've edited your question. Is the intent the same?

Comment: @cigien Yes, it is.

Comment: @Eljay I suppose it is, I was just wondering if there was a language construct for it. `for` loops are just `while` loops

Comment: @lajoh90686 you say you will consider `i == 0 || expensive_check()`. What is holding you back? It seems to be a perfect answer to your question.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you actually *want* there to be 2 different syntaxes for a `do-while` loop?

Comment: @cigien Yeah pretty much. Same reason why there is two syntaxes for the `while` loop :P

Comment: Why not handle an argument of `0` as a special case in your check function and don't do any work? Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool skip_start = true;
for(int i = 0; skip_start || i < 10; i++)
{
  if( i == 0 ) skip_start = false;
  // ... 
}
```

you mean something like this?

Comment: Why introduce another variable and check for something that is simply rearranging instructions?

Comment: If you believe that 'i < 10' is expensive, then, it could be that 'i==0' is equally expensive, depending on how 'i' works. So, in such a case, checking a bool is certainly not expensive.

Comment: simple solution, not expensive for memory. But `do-while` would be more appropriate. I don't know how much expensive is your `i < 10` but, comparing bool should be super fast. Moreover i think compilator should optimize it even more

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the first time the loop condition is evaluated, it will pass, then the simplest refactor is to hoist the body out of the loop:

```
// body (replace uses of i with 0)

for (int i = 1; f(i); ++i)  // start loop from 1 instead of 0
{
  // body
}
```